# Admin UI interface for mvc.net 4

Tags: c#, web-applications, asp.net-mvc-4

I've been searching for along time for an admin interface generator, for mvc.net 4. I noticed that there are similar tools for different environments (such as http://activeadmin.info/ for Ruby on Rails).

My main goal is to give an admin user all the CRUD options (New, Edit etc.), but also add other features such as forms etc. Also, this should be something generic, so it won't have to be re-written for each app.

Can anybody point out on such a tool for mvc.net 4?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that there is a tool that will generate a whole interface for you nor be entirely generic, however, there is built-in functionality to generate a CRUD Controller (and corresponding views) from within your project if you're using Entity Framework.

Right click your project file, and add a new controller and you are presented with Templates. Choosing `MVC controller with read/write actions and views, using Entity Framework` will allow you to select your model and entities class, and then generate forms for you.

[image: Add Controller R/W]

Most of the time you can begin using the forms immediately, however sometimes they may need minor modifications (best example I can think of is if you're using `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` as your key). You will need to add authorisation for the controllers too.

Of course, if you're not using Entity Framework, this won't be of much help to you.